# Saber si un base64 lleva encabezado

Tags: php

solo quisiera conocer si hay alguna forma de saber si un base64 lleva encabezado.

Por ejemplo

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKQAAA #para una imagen png

data:application/pdf;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKQAAA #para un archivo pdf

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKQAAA #base64 sin encabezado
```

Para aclarar solo necesito saber si el base64 lleva o no encabezado.

Comment: Verifica si hay `,` que es lo que separa ambas partes.

Comment: Actualmente eso es lo que hago pero quería saber si existe una función específica para hacer eso.

Comment: Podrías usar `$lleva_encabezado = (strpos($base64, ',') !== false);`